# MySQL Syntax Error - Array to Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pre-constructed array created from some test data as I have not yet set up a post form. The array looks like this:

```
$ud = array('name' => 'name', 'username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password', 'location' => 'london', 'platform' => 'mobile', 'developer_or_designer' => 'developer', 'tags' => 'hello', 'paypal_email' => 'email@email.com', 'developer_or_client' => 'developer', 'email' => 'email@email.com');

foreach ($ud as $key => $value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

From this array, I then try to insert the data via a MySQL query into my database:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Developers` (`Name`,`Email`,`Username`,`Password`,`Location`,`Platform`,`Developer_or_Designer`,`Tags`, `Paypal_Email`) VALUES (" . $ud['name'] . ", " . $ud['email'] . ", " . $ud['username'] . ", " .$ud['password'] . ", " . $ud['location'] . ", " . $ud['platform'] . ", " . $ud['developer_or_designer'] . ", " . $ud['tags'] . ", " . $ud['paypal_email'] . ")") or die(mysql_error());
```

However, it dies with the following error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@email.com, username, password, london, mobile, developer, hello, email@email.com)' at line 1`

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around each value in parenthases

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. [As Jeff notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700590/mysql-syntax-error-array-to-query/7700593#7700593), you need to put quotes around the strings.
2. Before putting quotes around them, you need to pass each string through [`mysql_real_escape_sring()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: I am running mysql_real_escape_string before

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Developers` (`Name`,`Email`,`Username`,`Password`,`Location`,`Platform`,`Developer_or_Designer`,`Tags`, `Paypal_Email`) VALUES ('" . $ud['name'] . "', '" . $ud['email'] . "', '" . $ud['username'] . "', '" .$ud['password'] . "', '" . $ud['location'] . "', '" . $ud['platform'] . "', '" . $ud['developer_or_designer'] . "', '" . $ud['tags'] . "', '" . $ud['paypal_email'] . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

try it:)

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of the column names those are `varchar` column types so you need to wrap your values with quotes:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Developers` (`Name`,`Email`,`Username`,`Password`,`Location`,`Platform`,`Developer_or_Designer`,`Tags`, `Paypal_Email`) VALUES ('" . $ud['name'] . "', '" . $ud['email'] . "', '" . $ud['username'] . "', '" .$ud['password'] . "', '" . $ud['location'] . "', '" . $ud['platform'] . "', '" . $ud['developer_or_designer'] . "', '" . $ud['tags'] . "', '" . $ud['paypal_email'] . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also if the values are coming from user input you should run each value through `mysql_real_escape_string` to help prevent against SQL injection attacks

Comment: You still need the quotes, `mysql_real_escape_string` sanitises the input but does not add the quotes necessary for the query to be valid

Comment: Also if you want the `mysql_real_escape_string` to have any effect you need to access the value by reference: `foreach ($ud as $key => &$value) {`...

Answer (score 0):

See this:

VALUES (" . $ud['name'] . ",

Nedd that:

VALUES ('" . $ud['name'] . "',

And for other columns too (if is not numberic)